# SharePoint Online: Modern Team Site Collections having same web Id

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, modern-team-site

We have created two new modern team site collections and both having same web Id. We have used "../_api/web/Id" URL to check the web Id.

Also we have tried in another SP Online tenancy and there also same problem.
For the sites that we created few days back we have different Ids

Let us know how to troubleshoot/resolve this issue?

Comment: did you create using some template?

Comment: No created from SharePoint Admin Center